# Mobile Nav Menu - Responsive Formatting

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm currently stuck on making a navigation menu mobile-friendly. My desired effect is to have the logo sit on the left side of the screen and the menu button to justify on the right. Whenever you click on the menu button, it will toggle the menu below the logo and the menu button. However, the menu is either appearing on the right side of both logo and menu, menu and logo are sticking together, or some other issue.

Solutions that I've tried:

- float:right on #menu. The issue with this is that is pushes the menu button up a line or down a line, and it's no longer vertically aligned with the logo.
- margin-right on .logo as a percentage. The issue with this is that it only keeps the menu button right-justified for a 20px range. Making it useless and creates a need for too many media queries

So how can I accomplish the desired the effect?

```
<header class="parent_header">
    <div class="main_header">
        <h2 class="logo"><a href="#">Kar Kompare</a></h2>
        <ul class="main_nav">
            <li><a href="#">Buy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">How It Works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

See my html here:https://jsfiddle.net/cfavela512/74x5975j/

Thanks for your help

Comment: Perhaps you could try to use `@media` to style `.main_nav` for both mobile and desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below css

```
    #menu {
        float: right;
        margin: 24px 0;
    }
   .logo {
       background:red;
       float: left;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 20px 0;
   }
  .main_nav {
      clear: both;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex-box like this,

```
.main_header{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.logo {
  flex: 1 auto;
  background: red;
}
#menu {
  flex: 1 auto;
  text-align: right;
}
.main_nav {
  flex: 1 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you nikhil. I like flex-box and will probably use this as a permanent solution in the near future when device support improves if it hasn't already.

Comment: I have rearranged the markup a bit to make it work without flex-box. See if it works. https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilkumar80/74x5975j/5/